# Lambda Expression with List<>

Tags: c#

I have this Boolean variable

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio
```

The variable above is **true** when:
`IcObrigatorio == 0` and `DsPathDocumento` is Null or Empty.

I want to set this variable to `true` using this:

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.ForEach(l => l.IcObrigatorio & string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento));
```

The code above does not set the variable to `true`. I don't get an error, but the variable stays `false` (default). I need to change the value of the variable. All of the conditions needed to set the variable are achieved. 
These are the conditions: `IcObrigatorio == 0` and `DsPathDocumento` is Null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you want `All()` or `Any()`.

Comment: "this way do not work" - in what way? *Always* give the error message, exception, or unwanted output. Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Are you also missing the second `&`?

Comment: I think It's really hard to read your question. Have you considered trying portuguese stackoverflow? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @EduardoWada Did not your comment. The fact that I am Brazilian can not ask here ?

Comment: I'm also brazilian and even though I know portguese grammar, I still can't understand your english, while you can ask here, you are more likely to receive low-quality answers as a consequence of bad commmunication, not to mention you add noise to this site as people will waste their time trying to figure out what you are asking and your question is not likely to be a good reference to future visitors of the site.

Comment: Ps: I didn't downvote your question, but I'm pretty sure what I'm saying is the reason behind it

Comment: You say that your code "do not work". *How* does it not work? Do you get any specific error message? Does it delete all of your files?

Comment: @RobertColumbia, there was almost 3 years this post. I was working in the Scania and now i don't work. Sincerely, i don't remember more. I guess that i was to set variable to true with the lambda expression and i was not getting. I guess. Giorgi Nakeuri posted a correct code, changing from  **Foreach** to **All** below look like.

Comment: I was trying to help you improve your question so you can get more upvotes and fewer downvotes. If you can figure out what the problem was and edit your question with the information, you could get it reopened and maybe even upvoted.

Comment: I can reopen a closed post? I guess was not possible. If i can reopen and get upvote, i'm go try to remember and edit this post. Ididn't know that is possible. Thanks, @RobertColumbia

Comment: You are welcome. You need 3k reputation to vote to reopen, which I have. Edit your question to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will vote to reopen it. This will push the question into the Reopen Votes Queue where, if four other people with 3k rep agree, the question will be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, thank you for help me and all in this site that are helping me.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, this question still is closed and maybe i still remain ban. I cannot to ask. What do i must to do to reopen this question? I try to improve and i got it, but. I don't have reputation enough to reopen.

Comment: @pnet the reviewers decided to keep the question closed. Perhaps they felt that your code was not fully reproducible - can you edit it into something that anyone can just paste in and compile?

Comment: @RobertColumbia, i understood. Really my code is not fully reproducible as said you. This code i posted at Feb/15 almost 3 years ago. I was working in the Scania and i left scania in April/15. I cannot to edit no longer. Well i must accept my ban. I hope someday i left to be ban.

Comment: @pnet the ban is temporarily lifted every six months to let you ask *one* question. That allows you to gain upvotes. You can also answer questions.

Comment: When you started help me, i was able to ask after to improve this question, but i was not issue or doubt to ask. When i ansewred a question, the owner of the question give me upvote and he said that my answer solved your question. Then i went to ask and i didn't get. So i received some downvotes for my answer and since i don't get to ask no longer. @RobertColumbia, thanks for all. Person like you earn good things. God bless you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use All function for this:

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.All(l => l.IcObrigatorio & string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check for all items to satisfy the condition then use `All()` , If you want to check that atleast one satisfies the condition then use `Any()`:

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.All(l => l.IcObrigatorio & string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento));
```